# Seaborn barplot: isna is not defined for MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, series

I would like to use seaborn `barplot()` to create a bar chart from a multi-indexed Series. I have grouped my dataset by two variables:

```
module_7_a_df = module_7_df.groupby(by=['Reported Race "MONRACE"', 'Hispanic Origin "HISPORIG"'])['SENTENCE CAP "SENSPCAP"'].count()
```

Grouping the dataframe creates a Series. This is what the resulting Series looks like:

[image: picture of resulting series]

When I try to create a barplot, I keep getting an error stating 'isna is not defined for MultiIndex.' The code for the barplot is:

```
sns.barplot(x=module_7_a_df.values, y=module_7_a_df.index)
```

This code works for Series created where the data has only been grouped by one column.

Can someone understand how to deal with this error?

Answer (score 1):

Remove all nan values from the columns you groupby before you group them.

```
module_7_a_df.dropna(subset=['Reported Race "MONRACE"', 'Hispanic Origin "HISPORIG"'])
```

Answer (score 1):

When you have a multi-index, you need to `reset_index` and when use `hue =` to enable the grouping, using an example dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset("tips")
counts = df.groupby(['time','day']).size()

counts

time    day 
Lunch   Thur    61
        Fri      7
        Sat      0
        Sun      0
Dinner  Thur     1
        Fri     12
        Sat     87
        Sun     76
dtype: int64
```

Then with the following:

```
counts = counts.to_frame('counts').reset_index()
sns.barplot(data = counts, x = "time",y="counts",hue="day")
```

[image]